# How to modify HTTP responses in a different .NET process

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I have a standard web server that serve web pages.

I want to monitor traffic on port 80, intercept every http responses, and add/inject an additionnal header to them.

The process will then act like a proxy between the web server and the client.

Could you please give me some pointers? I'm already aware of [SharpPCap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/), but I'm not sure where to start.

Note: I can't rely on the web server, I can't control it or change it's configuration. However I can install any other process on the same machine.

Thanks a million

Comment: Doing this in SharpPcap you'd essentially need to turn your host into a man-in-the middle by manipulating the arp tables on all the local hosts to direct to your host as if it was a router, hack the packets, and forward the results to the router. Like the rest of the answers say, there are *much* easier ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that SharpPCap is an overkill here.

Try:

- listen on a port (say 8080)
- for each incoming connection, accept and open one to the server (original one, port 80)
- pass everything that comes in from the client straight to the server
- pass everything that comes from the server back to the client, monitoring the stream and injecting/modifying if needed

Comment: Maybe you should reconsider, because it seems like you'll have to replicate and modify one OSI layer completely.  Imagine that you have to add to a TCP packet and it is already of maximum size?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do can be done with IIS 7.0 URL Rewrite module instead of rolling your own code.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/711/modifying-http-response-headers/